# execute exe nodejs, flag on completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, client

I got an exe file i'm running from my server, like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn; 
var testing= spawn('testing.exe');
if (data.type === "start") {
            testing.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
              console.log(data.toString());

               runTest();

           });
}
```

it all works and I can see in the console everything that runs.

However I would like a flag after the exe has completed so i can alert the client that the run was a success.

I **don't** want to add the line "completed successfully"  in the exe and parse 
it. Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for close and error events to get notified about the end of execution:

```
testing.on('close', function(code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code}`);
  } else {
    console.log('Child process completed successfully');
  }
});

testing.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Child process failed.');
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks